# Connecting cables to Rohloff hub external gear mech

Tags: rohloff

I am connecting the cables to the Rohloff hub external gear mech.  The instructions say to align the shifter to gear 1 and gear 14.  The shifter actually rotates past the one and past the 14, by roughly the amount of another gear stop.

Am I correct to interpret this exactly as stated, and not at the far ends of the range?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer turns out to be no.  Need to rotate the shifter all the way to the stops, beyond 1st and 14th gears:

"make sure the cable is taut before cutting" around 1:12.